# Why is WPA-encrypted ad-hoc mode disabled in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, internet-connection, hot-spot

Or, alternatively, how can I check that some WiFi chip supports WPA-encrypted hotspot creation? Is it hardware-dependent? Is anyone able to create WPA-encrypted hotspot?

Update: See the discussion at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3874

Related bug reports:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/905748

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654772

Comment: "how can I check that some WiFi chip supports WPA" with your model device. "Is it hardware-dependent?" There is many router that doesn't but there is an algorithmic (TKIP) that solve that compatibility problem.

Comment: Notice: I'm talking about Ubuntu in a hotspot mode, not about routers

Comment: As an aside, this may be a kernel incompatiblity problem, as the GNOME bug tracker [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654772#c1) suggests that newer kernels do not work with WPA / WPA2 on Ad-Hoc networks.

Answer (score 2):

Both the `SIOCSIWENCODEEXT` and `SIOCSIWGENIE` errors are usually intimately associated with WPA/`wpa_supplicant` failure.

Have you tried recompiling the latest RT2790 driver **with *wpa_supplicant* support enabled -- by default it's NOT!**. Also, note that it *only supports WPA PSK* for adhoc (see line 280 of `README_STA` below)

1. Get the [latest driver](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5018), download, extract, `cd` to the directory.
2. Inside `os/linux/config.mk`, find lines 10-14, which read:

   ```
   # Support Wpa_Supplicant
   HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=n
   # Support Native WpaSupplicant for Network Maganger
   HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n
   ```
3. Change the `n` at the end of both those lines to `y`.
4. `make` and `sudo make install` the driver (you'll need kernel headers, etc - comment if you need more info on the process).

Reboot, and see if things are any different (errors, etc.) with WPA adhoc.

If not:

1. Following the `README_STA` file in the extracted directory, copy it `cp RT2860STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/RT2860STA.dat`
2. Open that file, and change:

   - `NetworkType=Adhoc`
   - `Authmode=WPANONE` : **important** only this (WPA PSK) is supported for adhoc
   - Try `EncrypType=NONE` (and even TKIP and AES, because README does not say which is supported for adhoc)
   - Set `WPAPSK` to the key -- ***wpa_supplicant* may not be fully supported in adhoc*
3. Unload/load the the module to make it take effect: `rmmod` and `modprobe`, respectively.
4. See the `README_STA` file for more parameters and details, and try experimenting. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of town with a very limited GPRS traffic, can't check the solution right now. Also, I was asking a generic question, I don't really like your edits  since all notebooks with 12.04 I've met wasn't being able to create WPA-encrypted hotspot. And that's a big issue that should not be split into hardware-specific discussions.

Comment: @int_ua: I understand, I reverted the edits.

Answer (score 0):

To start a WPA adhoc network, create wpa-adhoc.conf:

```
ap_scan=2 network={
        ssid="test adhoc"
        mode=1
        frequency=2412
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-NONE
        pairwise=NONE
        group=TKIP
        psk="passphrase" }
```

And start it by running:

```
wpa_supplicant -cwpa-adhoc.conf -iwlan0 -Dwext
```

**Useful resources:**

- Find the chipset of your wireless and check if it's supported [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported).

*Alternatively*, in case that WPA encryption is not supported you could establish a VPN between hosts, either using [OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN) or even [SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHHowto).

Sources:

1. [Creating an ad hoc network](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc#Creating_an_ad_hoc_network).
2. [Wireless Cards Supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported#Wireless_Cards)

Comment: Why NONE? Can we use TKIP for example? Trying this.

Comment: And it creates open adhoc network, no encryption at all.

Comment: @int_ua : Just to clarify, have you tried this and you resulted with an open adhoc network?

Comment: Yes, I've copied the config adding only new lines where they should be and changing the password and executed the wpa_supplicant command with sudo. It showed a couple of `ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument` and the network is showed as non-encrypted on Nokia N900. The output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1059026/